# Starting a Play 2.4.2 project in IntelliJ Ultimate 14.1.4

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, intellij-14

I'd like to start a Play 2.4.2 project in IntelliJ, but when I create a Play application through the project wizard it uses Play 2.3.8. I checked the scala plugin and it is version 1.5.2, so I tried to update it to 1.7.1 to see if that made a difference, but got the response that it's not compatible with the current version. Same response with 1.6.1. I don't understand why since I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ.

I'm thinking of creating a Play 2.4.2 project and then importing it, but will this cause problems with IntelliJ? Thanks for any advice on the best way to approach this - I'm obviously v. new to all this, and can't find any similar issues anywhere with solutions to try.

Comment: I created my Play 2.4 project using activator and then imported it into intellij with no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, creating project with Activator won't cause any problems and is expected way to do this, just after creating it import id to IntelliJ as a SBT project (choose SDK version 1.8 and also check options to download sources and docs for easier work)

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the bundled version of sbt use the same as activator